# How to refresh a component on routing change when on the same component?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I am working on an angular 4 project and stuck in the following situation:

I have a two step booking form that is used for booking an appointment. I have two different industries lets say Industry A and Industry B, now when I am doing a booking lets say for industry A and go to step 2 and suppose I click other industry B(accessible by side menu) I am still stuck at step 2, I would like the page to be reloaded to step 1, so in short I want to access the same component with different routings.

In technical language, Am on a component and I want to refresh same component when routing is change.
If anyone know about please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are your routes defined?

Comment: I have a routes like http://localhost:3000/detail/music. the term music is dynamic. I want to access same component with music, movie etc and want to refresh component everytime when route change.

Comment: Try to change your route definition to something like this:

      { path: 'industry/:type', component: FormComponent }

Comment: I used the same approach, But my requirement is that, In the component there is a form, I want to refresh this form when route is change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this may it solves your problem

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from  '@angular/router';

export class xyz {
   constructor (private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

   }

   ngOnInit() {
       // calls form when route parms change,
       // the method calls when your route params will change
       this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe (res => {
          this.validateForm();
       }    
   }

   // build form
   validateForm () {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a design problem : simply create a Map object with the status for each company like this : formProgress[company][step] then check the values on route changes. Then in your HTML create a form and all the steps as individual components so that on each HTML tag you can use something like `<div *ngIf="step===2">`

For route changes detection simply compare window.href.location or the previous route in a variable, with activatedRoute params (this step needs you to learn more on routing)

Comment: my step-one and step-two exist on same component. I just need to refresh the component when routing is change.

Comment: It can exists in same component too create a step var and use ngIf in your HTML div instead of individual component

Comment: Its not a proper step form, it act like a step form with hide/show form sections. Your window.href.location is not a good solution.

Comment: That's why using ngIf or class.hidden you can achieve this on each HTML tag you want to display or not. For the route window.location.href is available on every browser to tell you what's the current URL (full url) so it will always work but for a proper app I would use routing to catch the params / route in URL.